# Best Practice : Store Large Form Values into Database

Tags: php, mysql, foreach

Suppose I've a large form, 25 fields consisting of textboxes, radio buttons, checkboxes, select tags, textareas etc.

Once the form is submitted, what would be the best way to collect those values and then store them into database; by best practice I mean **using as minimal lines of code as possible**.

*There is the traditional way:*

```
$name = $_POST['name'];
$age = $_POST['age'];
$city = $_POST['city'];
```

*which is definitely not the way to go.*

*There is then another way :*

```
foreach($_POST['submit'] as $key=>$val)
{
 $$key = $val;
}
```

*but again this will require a huge INSERT SQL statement:*

```
"INSERT INTO tablename (col1, col2, col3, col4,...col25)
 VALUES('$var1', '$var2', '$var3',.....'$var25')"
```

Using **foreach to capture values** is good, but then it comes with an elongated SQL INSERT statement. I'm sure there must a better way to use the INSERT statement. Ideas, suggestions, critics are all welcome.

Thanks,
Nisar

Comment: "by best practice I mean using as minimal lines of code as possible" — That isn't the normally accepted definition of the term … for good reason.

Comment: I think the time you're using here to get a short solution would better be invested to build a secure and complete one. If you have a lot of database interaction anyway, I would suggest using a library that does some abstraction for you so you don't have to mess with queries at all...

Comment: @s1lence I'm open to all suggestions.

Comment: Why did this question deserve a downvote?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

In HTML  change as follows

```
<input type="text" name="pval[name]" value="test" />
<input type="city" name="pval[city]" value="Bangalore" />
```

Then in the server side

**Updated :**

```
// Need to have the predefined array which is having valid fields
$fields = array('name', 'city');

$pval = $_POST['pval'];
foreach( $pval as $field_name => $val ){

   if( ! isset($fields[$field_name]) ){ // If it is not a valid field name

      unset($pval[$field_name]);
   }

}

if( count($pval) > 0 ){

$pval = array_map( 'mysql_real_escape_string', $pval );

//Then its easy to write the query as follows

    $qry = "INSERT INTO table_name( ". implode( ',', array_keys( $pval ) ) .") values( '". implode( "','", $pval ) . "')";  
}
```

Comment: My, what big security holes you have.

Comment: @Quentin Please see the updated answer for the following line `$pval = array_map( 'mysql_real_escape_string', $pval );`

Comment: @Quentin Appreciate your inputs, but my focus right now is cutting down the amount of code to be written. I'm aware that the code supplied here is prone to attacks but I can take care of that once I have a solid approach to follow

Comment: @asprin — The solid approach is to be clear and explicit over being concise. Conciseness is only a virtue when it doesn't infringe on clarity.

Comment: this still is very dangerouse because a user can change the input field names to get a completely different sql query. (e.g. insert into fields that should not be writable by a user directly)

Comment: Giving examples with the to-be-deprecated mysql_* functions is not the way to go when you ask me..

Comment: @Robinv.G. Agree totally. That's why I'm waiting for more responses

Answer (score 0):

You don't need that traditional way, you can use `extract` function  like:

`extract($_POST);`

This will make all indexes as variables with values.

In other way, to store in database, you can either `serialize` values or store in `JSON` format. And then store whole form values as single entry in DB (if there is nothing relational and purpose is only to store values.)

Comment: Hmm..extract and serialize are new to me. Let me take a look at them.

Comment: extract is alternative to traditional way. You don't need if using serialize or JSON.

Comment: Alright, but I would like to have a look at other responses too before I select the 'accepted answer'. Hope you understand.

Comment: Don't use extract. You allow external input to determine your local variable names. That is dangerous. (`$sql` could be overwritten, for example).

Comment: What is the point of having a relational database if you store serialised data in it? You won't be able to query the data.